# Can't connect to VPN using Checkpoint SNX

Tags: networking, vpn

I've been using Checkpoint SNX to login into a vpn for the past 6 months and today upon using the command

```
snx -s "my vpn" -u "user"
```

the program appears to just fail without error or any kind of indication as to why it's not working.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is failing or how I can view a log to find out what's going on?

My account credentials work on other machines when connecting to the vpn but not this one.
So far I've restarted the machine and uninstalled and reinstalled snx - same issue.

I would post a screenshot but I do not have the required reputation.

Here's a paste of my terminal output instead:

```
conor@IEDUB4044622A:~$ snx -s "VPN" -u "USER"
Check Point's Linux SNX
build 800007088
Please enter your password:
conor@IEDUB4044622A:~$
```

I've removed the actual vpn and username I'm using for obvious reasons.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT :**

I've figured out how to debug SNX and think I may have tracked down the issue

```
[ 7993 -148556032]@IEDUB4044622A[29 Jul 12:00:26] CkpRegDir: Environment variable CPDIR is not set.
[ 7993 -148556032]@IEDUB4044622A[29 Jul 12:00:26] GenerateGlobalEntry: Unable to get registry path
[ 7993 -148556032]@IEDUB4044622A[29 Jul 12:00:26] rand_collect_entropy: Failed to collect entropy from all sources.
```

Comment: Please make the edited portion an answer so that future readers can take help from your post..also don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the potential answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Comment: @heemayl The edited portion is just additional info on the problem, not a solution/answer.

Comment: My conclusion was based on _ I may have tracked down the issue _

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for now.

Rolling back Ubuntu to a previous issue upon booting solved the issue for me. Seems to be a problem with newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: "upon booting" - do you mean an older kernel? Or you (re)installed an older Ubuntu version - if so, which version?